# How do I run a method every 10 minutes in Android?

Tags: android

I am looking to run a certain method call every ten minutes in Android, what is the best way to go about implementing this? I am currently looking at using the `Handler` object's `PostDelayed`  method.

Comment: If you need to run it repeatedly (every ten minutes), why not to use `Timer` and `TimerTask`?

Comment: Is this in an activity? Or is this something that you are expecting to run when there are no activities on the screen? The answer to your question depends heavily upon this.

Comment: Do you want to do that in the background of your application (like reload some text view from the web every 10 minutes) or the background of the phone (like the music player for example).

Comment: The exact situation is I have a service that needs to send a text message every ten minutes after it is started until it is told to stop. I apologize, I should have been more specific in my original question.
@Asahi Wouldn't that be less memory efficient than just using the Handler?
@CommonsWare It is not an activity, but I am curious as to why I would handle it differently if it was.

Comment: I am not sure - curious myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Handler` and `PostDelayed` is the way to go, at the end of your `Runnable` have it make the call `mHandler.postDelayed(Runnable, 10 minutes)`